# Formulating equations for 3D stress in the finite element method

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, solidmechanics

I would like to know how you formulate equations for the finite element method for stress calculations. We know the answer because user21 has put it [here](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/pdes-and-finite-elements/structural-mechanics-in-3d.html).  It involves usage of `Inactive` in stopping the equations from simplifying too early. I am almost there with formulating the equations but need a straightforward method because I need to look at variants.

The general equations for the finite element method must be put into the form

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[See the second on Systems of Partial Differential Equations](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/SolvingPDEwithFEM.html#243862001)

here u, v and w are the displacements in the three directions. The $c_{i j}$ are 3 by 3 matrices which we have to find. The other coefficients are vectors which we don't need for a stress formulation.

From a standard engineering textbook we find that the strain is related to the stress by

```
strainStress = {
    ϵx[x, y, z] == 
     1/Y (σx[x, y, 
         z] - ν (σy[x, y, z] + σz[x, y, z])),
    γxy[x, y, z] == 1/G τxy[x, y, z],
    γxz[x, y, z] == 1/G τxz[x, y, z],

    γyx[x, y, z] == 1/G τyx[x, y, z],
    ϵy[x, y, z] == 
     1/Y (σy[x, y, 
         z] - ν (σx[x, y, z] + σz[x, y, z])),
    γyz[x, y, z] == 1/G τyz[x, y, z],

    γzx[x, y, z] == 1/G τzx[x, y, z],
    γzy[x, y, z] == 1/G τzy[x, y, z],
    ϵz[x, y, z] == 
     1/Y (σz[x, y, 
         z] - ν (σx[x, y, z] + σy[x, y, z]))
    } /. G -> Y/(2 (1 + ν));
```

Here `σx[x, y, z]`, `σy[x, y, z]` and `σz[x, y, z]` are the normal stresses and  `τxy[x, y, z]`, `τxz[x, y, z]` and `τyx[x, y, z]` are shear stresses. I have also put in shear stresses `τyx[x, y, z]`, `τzx[x, y, z]` and `τxy[x, y, z]` which I might have been able to avoid since there is symmetry. `Y` is Young's modulus and `G` is the shear modulus. `ν` is Poisson's ratio. I have substituted for the shear modulus because it is related to Young's modulus.

The relationship between strain and stress is given by

```
strainDisp={Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][x, y, z], Derivative[0, 1, 0][u][x, y, z] + 
  Derivative[1, 0, 0][v][x, y, z], Derivative[0, 0, 1][u][x, y, z] + 
  Derivative[1, 0, 0][w][x, y, z], Derivative[0, 1, 0][u][x, y, z] + 
  Derivative[1, 0, 0][v][x, y, z], Derivative[0, 1, 0][v][x, y, z], 
 Derivative[0, 0, 1][v][x, y, z] + Derivative[0, 1, 0][w][x, y, z], 
 Derivative[0, 0, 1][u][x, y, z] + Derivative[1, 0, 0][w][x, y, z], 
 Derivative[0, 0, 1][v][x, y, z] + Derivative[0, 1, 0][w][x, y, z], 
 Derivative[0, 0, 1][w][x, y, z]};
```

Thus the job we have before us is to find a matrix that relates stress and displacements and then put it in the form above. We can do this as follows:
First find a matrix that relates stress and strains. Then find a second matrix that relates strains and displacements and then multiply the two together. I do this as follows:

1. Make a list of the stress symbols and strain symbols
2. Solve for the stresses and then use `CoefficientArrays` to get a matrix (`mat`) for the stresses in terms of the strains.
3. Multiply the `mat` by the strains to get equations for the stresses in terms of the displacement derivatives.
4. Make a list of displacement derivatives.
5. Use `CoefficientArrays` again to get a matrix (`mat2`) for the stresses in terms of the displacement derivatives.
6. Partition `mat2` to get the matrices that are the $c_{i j}$ we need.

---

```
 stress = {
       σx[x, y, z], τxy[x, y, z], τxz[x, y, z],
       τyx[x, y, z], σy[x, y, z], τyz[x, y, z],
       τzx[x, y, z], τzy[x, y, z], σz[x, y, z]
       };
    strain = strainStress[[All, 1]];
    sol = stress /. Solve[strainStress, stress];
    {vec, mat} = 
      CoefficientArrays[Thread[stress == sol[[1]]], strain] // Normal;
    dd = Join[Grad[u[x, y, z], {x, y, z}], Grad[v[x, y, z], {x, y, z}], 
       Grad[w[x, y, z], {x, y, z}]];
    eq2 = -mat.strainDisp;
    {vec2, mat2} = 
      CoefficientArrays[Thread[stress == eq2], dd] // Normal // Simplify;
    mat3 = Partition[mat2 // Simplify // Factor, {3, 3}];
```

Is there a better way to go from textbook equations to here? Let me know if there is.

Now we have to put in lots of `Inactive` to get the equation we need for the finite element formulation in Mathematica. We need an `Inactive[Div]` and an `Inactive[Grad]` in lots of places. This is where I get lost and need help. My idea was to formulate this as in the expression above using symbols for the $c_{i j}$. Having got this formulation, in Inactive form I could then substitute in my 3 by 3 matrices for each $c_{i j}$.

Thus next I

7. Make a list of coefficients for the  $c_{i j}$, and a list of `Inactive` `Grad`s.
8. Make an expression for the  $c_{i j}$ and the `Grads`. This is half of what I need.

For the next step I am lost. I need to premultiply each   $c_{i j}$ by an `Inactive` `Div`. Then I would have my expression. How do I do this?

---

```
cc = Array[c, {3, 3}];
coffs = Thread[Flatten[cc, 1] -> Flatten[mat3, 1]];
idd = {Inactive[Grad][u[x, y, z], {x, y, z}], 
  Inactive[Grad][v[x, y, z], {x, y, z}], 
  Inactive[Grad][w[x, y, z], {x, y, z}]}
e1 = cc.idd // ExpandAll
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]